# How to find empty tr in table using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to find Empty tr in table, is there any way to find it?
after finding empty row I want to insert some data in it.

Comment: Did you try something ? For example iterating over the rows and looking at textContent||innerText ?

Comment: I am not familiar with javascript, so i did not yet.

Comment: What is an empty tr actually.. does it have empty td elements or no children at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better ways, this is what occurred to me.

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('td').length == 0) {
   // empty tr
   // id of tr is available through this.id
  }
});
```

Comment: He didn't say he want or is able to use Jquery

Comment: @reporter, You're right. My bad.

Comment: thanks majid, but now i want to add my old id content to this tr,
actually, structure is like this,
<tr></tr>
and in this empty tr<> I want to add new td<> with my old Id( this Id has data)

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand what you want to do, but if the tr has some id, you can get it inside the each function with `this.id`.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have this HTML :

```
  <table id=tbl>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> <!-- this line is empty -->
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Then you can fill the empty line like this :

```
var rows = document.getElementById('tbl').rows;
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
   var txt = rows[i].textContent || rows[i].innerText;
   if (txt.trim()==="") rows[i].innerHTML="<td>Something</td>";
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/emibuf/2/edit)

This uses :

- the [rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.rows) property of the table
- `textContent` (or `innerText` for IE) to get the content without the tags

As this also use the `trim` function which isn't available in IE8, you might want to add [this shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) :

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this `$('table tr:empty').html('....')`

Comment: He didn't say he want or is able to use Jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var table = tables[0];
var trs = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    if (trs[i].innerHTML === '') {
        console.log('EMPTY', trs[i]);
    } else {
        console.log('NOT EMPTY', trs[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its not easy. You can see [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/v6dyL/).
HTML:

```
<table id="table" style="border: 1px solid green;"><tbody>
    <tr id="empty"></tr>
    <tr id="withText"><font style="color: red;">text</font></tr>
    <tr id="withEmptyTd"><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="withTdWithText"><td>text</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var trs = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
var tr, id, text, tds, j, td, tdText;
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    tr = trs[i];
    id = tr.id;
    output.innerHTML += "Getting tr[" + id + "]<br />";
    text = tr.innerHTML;
    output.innerHTML += "tr[" + id + "].innerHTML = \"" + text + "\" it's length = " + text.length + "<br />";
    tds = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
    output.innerHTML += "tr[" + id + "] have " + tds.length + " tds<br />";
    for (j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
        td = tds[j];
        tdText = td.innerHTML;
        output.innerHTML += "tr[" + id + "] -> td[" + j + "].innerHTML = \"" + tdText + "\" its length = " + tdText.length + "<br />";
    }
}
```

And output will be:

```
Getting tr[empty]
tr[empty].innerHTML = "" it's length = 0
tr[empty] have 0 tds
Getting tr[withText]
tr[withText].innerHTML = "" it's length = 0
tr[withText] have 0 tds
Getting tr[withEmptyTd]
tr[withEmptyTd].innerHTML = "" it's length = 9
tr[withEmptyTd] have 1 tds
tr[withEmptyTd] -> td[0].innerHTML = "" its length = 0
Getting tr[withTdWithText]
tr[withTdWithText].innerHTML = "text" it's length = 13
tr[withTdWithText] have 1 tds
tr[withTdWithText] -> td[0].innerHTML = "text" its length = 4
```

Cause any tag or text **in tr but not in td** shows before the table.
[image: text in tr]